# Reloading a file with autoread throws an error related to undodir

Tags: autocmd

I have the following contents in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
set undofile
set undodir=$HOME/.vim/undodir

" https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/383044
autocmd FocusGained,BufEnter,CursorHold,CursorHoldI *
  \ if mode() !~ '\v(c|r.?|!|t)' && getcmdwintype() == '' | checktime | endif
set autoread
```

When a file is automatically read after an external change, I get the following error message:

> E828: Cannot open undo file for writing: `/path/to/undo/file`

How can I prevent this error from showing up?

EDIT 1:

It looks like this issue stems from the fact that the undo file name, which includes path information, is too long (i.e. more than 255 characters). I will post an answer if I find a solution to address this issue.

Comment: Why prevent the message instead of correcting the source error?

Comment: Both options are fine, especially if there's one that can fix the root cause of the issue.

Comment: `path is too long` So, is it Windows? Or *nix? It looks like *nix, but 255 chars shouldn't give any problem there.

Comment: @Matt I get this error on Ubuntu. `getconf NAME_MAX /` returns 255.

Comment: So it's a matter of path length :( The solution should be then to move the undodir… 

PS: I'm confused by Matt replying to Matt, it took me some time and mouse over to figure they're two different accounts :D

Comment: @gildux, no it is not about the location of `undodir`. Please read the quotes from the solution for the root cause of the problem and how one can solve it.

Comment: I see. Hopefully, the restriction is on filename length only here. Some (in fact many well known) operating systems have that issue on filepath too, that's why I though of shortening the undodir, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed [vim-undodir-tree](https://github.com/pixelastic/vim-undodir-tree) to solve the problem.

> As vim saves undo files in undodir with a name equal to the original filepath, with all / replaced with %, one can hit the OS maximum length for files. If this happens, vim won't be able to save the undo file and will throw the E828 error.

> Well, instead of saving undo files as %original%path%of%the%file, it will create the original/path/of/the/ folder structure inside of undodir, and save the undo file in it.

> This way, we avoid the length limit on filenames, and as an added bonus it makes pruning the undo folder much more easier.

Comment: Hey, original author of the plugin here. Thanks for using it. For the record, I'm no longer using this plugin as I've now switched to nvim that doesn't seem to be affected by this error. Also, small warning, you might encounter errors if you ever happen to create a `foo/bar` file, delete it, then create a `foo` file instead. My plugin doesn't handle this case well (overwriting a folder with a file).

Comment: @pixelastic, Thanks for developing this plugin and for the heads-up. I was thinking of writing my first plugin where I would hash the path and store `hash%filename`. But then I found your plugin, which is elegant and does the job for me.